# NullReferenceException on DevExpress 16.2.1 XtraReport generation via ReportService on WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

When using `ReportService` as report provider for `AspxDocumentViewer` in *DevExpress 2016 ver.1.2* `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` is shown as JS alert in browser when trying to show report.

Caught internal exception has next info:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.ReportRenderHelper.GetPreparedOptions() 
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.DocumentViewer.RemoteReportRenderHelper.CreatePageWebControl(IImageRepository imageRepository, Int32 pageIndex)
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.ReportRenderHelper.WritePage(Int32 pageIndex)
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.DocumentViewer.DocumentViewerReportWebRemoteMediator.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1(PrintingSystemBase printingSystem)
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.DocumentViewer.DocumentViewerRemoteHelper.DoWithRemoteDocument[T](Byte[] bytes, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageCount, Func`2 func)
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.DocumentViewer.DocumentViewerReportWebRemoteMediator.GetPage(ReportViewer viewer, RemoteDocumentInformation documentInformation, Int32 pageIndex)
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.DocumentViewer.DocumentViewerReportViewer.CallbackRemotePage()\r\n   at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ReportViewer.GetCallbackResult()
    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ASPxDocumentViewer.GetCallbackResult()
    at DevExpress.Web.ASPxWebControl.System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult()
```

During small investigation 've noticed that report generation crashes after request to `ReportService.GetPages` method somewhere in inner DevExpress code.

Pay attention, that same solution works ok using *DevExpress 15.2.7* so it's some kind of breaking changes between two versions.

Same solution also works in current version when report is set directly to `AspxDocumentViewer.Report` (not using `ReportServiceClientFactory` and `ReportService`), so it seems to be a `ReportService` issue.

ASP.Net WebForms application, report is as simple as possible (empty, no data usage).

Was created [ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T418299) on DevExpress site and it has in attach sample application to reproduce problem.

Comment: the error is telling you what is wrong.. usually this happens if you declare an object but do not create a new instance of the object for example if I create a `Datatable myDatatable;` and do not create `myDatatable = new DataTable()` in code or initialize the variable = null or new it there.. this would throw the error once ran on the target machine.. please show your actual code in regards to the where and how you are initializing the Object in question..

Comment: @MethodMan `Datatable myDatatable;` is not a creation but declaring. Sample code is attached in DevExpress ticket, link was mentioned behind. And yes it's `variable = null` problem as it's `NullReferenceException`. Thanks for help, but it was useless.

Comment: sounds like you should post code because what you have posted is actually useless..

Comment: Code is posted as attach in DevExpress ticket. (Link already mentioned in question or (the same) https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T418299 ). That code works in older version of library (and yes, I've reviewed breaking changes for new version - no related info found). So it's not a forgotten initialization of variable. I expect that there should be some extra parameter(s) initialized not mentioned in documentation or library bug. Here I'm asking for help from guys who maybe already encountered same problem in XtraReports.

Comment: _"Code is posted as attach in DevExpress ticket"_ -- we are not DevExpress support staff. It may be that DevExpress is using Stack Overflow as their support forum (or maybe not...I don't know). But if they are, posts requesting support from them are still expected to comply with Stack Overflow guidelines. That includes making sure your question has a good [mcve] in it that reliably reproduces the problem. See also [ask] for further advice on asking a clear, answerable question.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: _"we are not DevExpress support staff"_ - but we can help guys find here answers if they (as me) hadn't found on DevExp site. Or help guys share their knowledge, when official site didn't do this. That's why this question was made _after_ creation of related ticket on support site - as just duplicate for easy search. About code example - I've read your links some time ago but you didn't read my question thoroughly: _"same solution works ok using DevExpress 15.2.7"_, _"sample application to reproduce problem"_. My English is not native, but sapienty sat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using ReportService as report provider for AspxDocumentViewer in DevExpress 2016 ver.1.2 "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is shown as JS alert in a browser when trying to show report.

I see that you are using the **alpha version** (2016 ver.1.2).
AFAIK this issue is already  [fixed](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T400539) with maintenance update [16.1.5](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/WhatsNew/DXperience/files/16.1.5.xml) released on 2 August 2016.
Thus, upgrade the DX Suite to resolve this issue.

Comment: thanks. Have read also answer in related ticket, but have never found info you've mention in "fixed" link (maybe, because I had no access to it?). But still thank you

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry Vadim. I have updated the fixed link with the correct Uri.